# Adding an additional dimension to an array

Tags: julia

**Note:** This question/answer is copied from the Julia Slack channel.

If I have an arbitrary Julia `Array`, how can I add another dimension.

```
julia> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

The desired output would be e.g.:

```
julia> a[some_magic, :]
1×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3  4
```

Or:

```
julia> a[:, some_magic]
4×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

Comment: I did not see what was written on Slack, but I have shared what I typically do in this case, as it is indeed common.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A less tricky thing I usually do to achieve this is:

```
julia> reshape(a, 1, :)
1×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3  4

julia> reshape(a, :, 1)
4×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

(it also seems to involve less typing)

Finally a common case requiring transforming a vector to a column matrix can be done:

```
julia> hcat(a)
4×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

**EDIT** also if you add trailing dimensions you can simply use `:`:

```
julia> a = [1,2,3,4]
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4

julia> a[:,:]
4×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 1
 2
 3
 4

julia> a[:,:,:]
4×1×1 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

Answer (score 3):

The trick is so use `[CartesianIndex()]` to create the additional axes:

```
julia> a[[CartesianIndex()], :]
1×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3  4
```

And:

```
julia> a[:, [CartesianIndex()]]
4×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

If you want to get closer to numpy's syntax, you can define:

```
const newaxis = [CartesianIndex()]
```

And just use `newaxis`.